# number of n-vertex graphs degree $\leq$m

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How many cycle-free connected graphs are there on n vertices, none of which has degree >m?

e.g for m=1 there is 1 graph for n=1,2, 0 otherwise. For m=2 there is always 1 graph.

I am particularly interested in the m=4 case, as I was originally trying to count isomers of straight-chain alkanes.

Comment: One approach to the $m=4$ case is to calculate the answer for various small values of $n$ and then see if the result is in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: Not in OEIS, the first few terms are 1,1,1,3,5,9,18,35,75.

Comment: It is in OEIS: you missed a $2$ before the $3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OEIS sequence A000602](http://oeis.org/A000602) seems to be exactly what you want: ‘Number of n-node unrooted quartic trees; number of n-carbon alkanes C(n)H(2n+2) ignoring stereoisomers’, with extensive references. There’s a table of the values for $n=0$ through $n=60$ [here](http://oeis.org/A000602/b000602.txt). This sequence is discussed in [this paper](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/cayley.html) by Rains & Sloane and in P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick, *Analytic Combinatorics*, p. 478; the book is pretty heavy going, but it’s available for free download [here](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html). There does not appear to be any nice formula.

The $n=3$ case is [OEIS A000672](http://oeis.org/A000672), which also appears to have no nice formula.

Answer (score -1):

I see that 
If $B(z)$ is the OGF of alkanes (EIS [A000602](http://oeis.org/A000602)), which are unrooted trees, then
$B(z) = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + 2 z^4 + 3 z^5 + 5 z^6 + 9 z^7 + 18 z^8 + 35 z^9 + \ldots$

But what is the lower or upper bound on the coefficient of $z^n$?
It would be really helpful if you could tell something about it.

Comment: It appears to me that this answer provides the OEIS info that was already provided by Brian M. Scott, and pretty much nothing else.  If you have a question, you can ask that in a comment.  It is not fit for an answer.  And, this answer was 3.5 months later.